# How to update input box value based on row id

Tags: php, html, mysql

The web screenshot shows that the time value is fetched from database column settime, I want to insert my own value into the set time column and update that single row but upon clicking update it doesn't update.

If I were to replace the update query with delete query as shown below it works and delete that particular row. My question is how can I use same method to update that particular column value based on id.

```
<?php
    $id =(isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : null);
    if($id!=null) {
    $query="delete from activity where id=$id";
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    }
?>
```

**Web**

[image: web]

**database**

[image: database]

**timer.php**

```
<?php include 'header.php'; ?>
<div class="main" >
    <table width="900px" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
        <tr>
            <td style="width:10px"></td>
            <td style="background:#F2F2F2; height:400px">
                <?php
                $settime =(isset($_POST['settime']) ? $_POST['settime'] : null);
                    $id =(isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : null);
                    if($id!=null) {     
                        //$settime =(isset($_POST['settime']) ? $_POST['settime'] : null);
                        $query="update feedtime set settime='$settime' where id=$id";       
                        $result=mysql_query($query);    
                    }
                ?>
                <table width="100%" class="tableStyle">
                    <tr style="font-weight:bold">
                        <td>NO.</td>
                        <td>User</td>
                        <td>Time</td>
                        <td>Time Left</td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php 
                        $i=0;
                        $query="select * from feedtime";
                        $result=mysql_query($query);    
                        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                            $i+=1;
                            echo '
                    <tr style="height:25px">
                        <td>'.$i.'</td>
                        <td>'.$row['user'].'</td>
                        <td><input id="timer" type="text" name="settime" style="width:200px;" value='. $row['settime'].' /></td>
                        <td>'. $row['timeleft'] .'</td>';echo '
                        <td align="center"><input type="button" value="Update" style="font-size:10px;width:80px;height:25px;padding:0;margin:0" onclick="location.href=\'timer.php?id='.$row['id'].'\' " /></td>
                   </tr>';
                    }
                    if($i==0)echo '
                    <tr style="height:25px">
                        <td colspan="6">Record not found</td>
                    </tr>'; ?>
                </table><br>
                <?php echo mysql_error(); ?>
            </td>
        </tr>       
    </table>    
</div>
<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

Comment: its 2018. why are you still using `mysql_*` functions?

Comment: You need to use ajax for this...

Comment: Stop using deprecated mysql API. Use mysqli or PDO instead. Also use prepared Statements to prevent sql injection

Comment: Never `DELETE` via GET request, a cautionary tale ~ https://thedailywtf.com/articles/WellIntentioned-Destruction

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the implementation details for a second (like using the MySQL extension), your main problem appears to be submitting (by `POST`) a single `id` / `settime` pair of values.

I would simply make a form per row. Something like this (very simplified)

```
<?php while($row = fetch_some_data()) : ?>
<tr>
  <td>
    <input form="form<?= $row['id'] ?>" type="text" name="settime" value="<?= $row['settime'] ?>" />
  <td>
  <td>
    <form id="form<?= $row['id'] ?>" method="post" action="timer.php">
      <button type="submit" name="id" value="<?= $row['id'] ?>">UPDATE</button>
    </form>
  </td>
</tr>
<?php endwhile ?>
```

Note the [`form` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-form) on the `<input>` and `id` attribute on the `<form>` are the same. This lets you tie the input to that form without it being a descendant element, allowing you to include all the required data without bastardising the HTML to get the form to wrap the table-row.

---

With this, pressing any *"UPDATE"* button will submit a `POST` request with data like

```
id=1&settime=12%3A08%3A00
```

which you can retrieve in your script via `$_POST['id']` and `$_POST['settime']`.

For example (and using MySQLi)

```
if (isset($_POST['id'], $_POST['settime'])) {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('UPDATE `feedtime` SET `settime` = ? where `id` = ?');
    $stmt->bind_param('si', $_POST['settime'], $_POST['id']);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```